# ORA-01400: Error while inserting Foreign Key using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have two tables `A` & `B` with a foreign key from `B` to a called `FK_A`. I have a **not null** constraint on `FK_A`.

I have the following two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_A", nullable = true)
    private Set<B> b; 

    //getters setters etc.
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    //attributes, getters setters etc.
}
```

The reads work fine but when I try to write A to the DB, I get : ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into `("SCHEMA"."B"."FK_A")`

The code I am tring to insert the entity looks something like:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ab")
private EntityManager em;

A a = new A();
B b = new B();

Set<B> bList = new HashSet();
bList.add(b);
a.setB(bList);

em.persist(a);
```

Now if I am correct shouldn't hibernate automatically populate `FK_A` in table `B` based on the `id` it had autogenerated. If not how can I go about setting it?

Comment: How can you set `Set<B> b` with a `List<B> bList`?

Comment: Was converting it internally in my code. Will edit to correct it here

Comment: ;). Maybe `B` source could be useful for us.

Comment: @SurajMenon How did you create the table in the first place? I mean, in class `A`, the `b` variable is annotated with attribute `nullable=true` which mean the column should accept null value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mappedBy `OneToMany.mappedBy()`. JavaDoc:

```
The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.
```

It is a synonym for the Hibernate's keyword "inverse".

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5960739/835000).

In addition as a variant may be your class B has property for class A declared with `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` annotation.